# Images in wordpress, which way to go?

Tags: wordpress

I know we can use the Post thumbnails and the native images wordpress has: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails But there's yet another way of  having the images resized. And that is, using the image_resize function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize, which will resize the image to some specific dimensions.

Now, my question is...which one is better and which one would you recommend me to use if I want to develop one theme and want to use different-size thumbnails in different places?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need more than 3 different sizes (thumbnail, medium, large), you just have to set these sizes in media options.

If you need more, you can add new image size using [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

But in my opinion, the way wordpress handles image should be improved since it will create at least 3 files for each image you upload in media library... It should be better to create resized image only when needed and cache it (like [image cache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) with drupal).

You can use [**timthumb**](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) which is kind of image cache for wordpress, it is commonly used in premium themes but be sure to get latest version since there was a serious flaw in it last year.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @soju answer:

If you want to disable a default image, then set the `$width` and `$heigth` attributes to `0`. WP will then skip them on creation.